# Golang multiple recipients with gomail.v2

Tags: go, gomail

The only way that I've used to send emails via gomail.v2 is using the Send() function to each email in a for loop. But I need to show the other email addresses those the same email have been sent.

```
for _, recipient := range os.Args[3:] {
    mail.SetAddressHeader("From", "my@mail.com", "My Name")
    mail.SetHeader("To", recipient)
    mail.SetHeader("Subject", os.Args[2])
    mail.SetBody("text/html", os.Args[1])

    if err := dialer.DialAndSend(mail); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Could not send email to %q: %v", recipient, err)
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I've found something like:

```
var emails bytes.Buffer

mail.SetAddressHeader("From", "my@mail.com.br", "My Name")
mail.SetHeader("Subject", os.Args[2])
mail.SetBody("text/html", os.Args[1])

for _, recipient := range os.Args[3:] {
    emails.WriteString(recipient + ",")
}

mail.SetHeader("To", emails.String())

if err := dialer.DialAndSend(mail); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Could not send email to %q: %v", buffer, err)
    panic(err)
}
```

It works by sending the email only to the first recipient in the String.
And in the email manager like Gmail, Outlook or any other the other recipients addresses are showed, but not sent.

How should I do that properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give this a try?

```
recipients := os.Args[3:]
addresses := make([]string, len(recipients))
for i, recipient := range recipients {
    addresses[i] = mail.FormatAddress(recipient, "")
}

mail.SetHeader("To", addresses...)

if err := dialer.DialAndSend(mail); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: What means the "addresses..." (the 3 dots?)

Comment: ... is a Go language construction for slice expansion: 

if addresses has 3 elements

```mail.SetHeader("To", addresses...) ```

will be equal to 

```mail.SetHeader("To", addresses[0], addresses[1], addresses[2]) ```

Answer (score 3):

extending the example above

```golang
type recipient struct {
    Name    string   `json:"Name"`
    Address string   `json:"Address"`
}

func sendToMultipleRecipientsWithGomailV2(recipients []recipient, subject, message string) {
    mail := gomail.NewMessage()

    addresses := make([]string, len(recipients))
    for i, recipient := range recipients {
        addresses[i] = mail.FormatAddress(recipient.Address, recipient.Name)
    }


    mail.SetHeader("From", "myaddress@gmail.com")
    mail.SetHeader("To", addresses...)
    mail.SetHeader("Subject", subject)
    mail.SetBody("text/html", message)

    dialer := gomail.Dialer{Host: "smtp.gmail.com", Port: 587, Username:"myaddress@gmail.com", Password: "mypassword"}
    if err := dialer.DialAndSend(mail); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    mail.Reset()
}


func main() {
    recipients := []recipient{{
        Name:    "User 1",
        Address: "user1@gmail.com",
    },{
        Name:    "User 2",
        Address: "user2@yandex.com",
    }}

    sendToMultipleRecipientsWithGomailV2(recipients, "my subject", "my message")
}
```

https://gist.github.com/kmilodenisglez/ab6518ca77172fdd646501b04bafb479