# Gomail.v2 - Multiple recipiens from Slice

Tags: go, slice, gomail

Disclaimer: I have seen a similar question in this thread:
[Golang multiple recipients with gomail.v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066003/golang-multiple-recipients-with-gomail-v2) but cannot get this to work, and do not yet have the juice to comment there asking for help. The op in that question is using `os.Args[]`, whereas I want to use a slice stored in a config file.

I'm attempting to use the awesome gomail.v2 package to send to a list of *multiple recipients* contained in a slice `ToMail` in instance `e` of struct `Email` via my method `Mail`.

The compiler complains at line 37:

```
./mailer.go:37: not enough arguments in call to m.SetAddressHeader
        have (string, []string...)
        want (string, string, string)
```

How can I properly pass each recipient in my slice to the `SetAddressHeader("To"`... method so as to send to all recipients in slice `ToMail`?

What I've tried:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
)

type Email struct {
        FromMail, FromFirstLast, Password, Subject, Body, Server string
        ToMail []string
        Port int
}

func main() {
        e := Email{FromMail: "fromuser@foo.com",
                FromFirstLast: "From User",
                ToMail: []string{"user1@foo.com", "user2@foo.com"},
                Password: "passpasspass",
                Subject: "Test",
                Body:"TEST BODY",
                Server: "foo.foomail.com",
                Port: 587,}
        err := e.Mail()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }
}

func (e Email)Mail() (error) {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetAddressHeader("From", e.FromMail, e.FromFirstLast)
    addresses := make([]string, len(e.ToMail))

    for i, _ := range addresses{
        addresses[i] = m.FormatAddress(e.ToMail[i], "")
    }
    m.SetAddressHeader("To", addresses...)
    m.SetHeader("Subject", e.Subject)
    m.SetBody("text/plain", e.Body)

    d := gomail.NewPlainDialer(e.Server, e.Port, e.FromMail, e.Password)
    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        return err
    }
        return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [package gomail](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2)
>
> ```
> import "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
> ```
>
> [func (*Message) SetAddressHeader](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#Message.SetAddressHeader)
>
> ```
> func (m *Message) SetAddressHeader(field, address, name string)
> ```
>
> SetAddressHeader sets an address to the given header field.
>
> [func (*Message) SetHeader](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#Message.SetHeader)
>
> ```
> func (m *Message) SetHeader(field string, value ...string)
> ```
>
> SetHeader sets a value to the given header field.

The example you referenced and the documentation has, for multiple addresses:

```
addresses := make([]string, len(e.ToMail))
for i := range addresses {
    addresses[i] = m.FormatAddress(e.ToMail[i], "")
}
m.SetHeader("To", addresses...)
```

But you write, using the single address (with implicit `FormatAddress`) form:

```
m.SetAddressHeader("To", addresses...)
```

Error:

```
not enough arguments in call to m.SetAddressHeader
        have (string, []string...)
        want (string, string, string)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I assumed `SetHeader` was just from the v1 API, and that `SetAddressHeader` was current. Not the case! `SetHeader` worked for me, thank you!